# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, classcastexception

I have a `List`, which I am trying to use in 2 different ways...

```
private List<List<List<String>>> mListSelectedsWeekDAY;

// technique 1
for(int t = 0; t < mListSelectedsWeekDAY.get(0).get(0).size();t++){
    ...
}

// technique 2
List<String> tmpList = mListSelectedsWeekDAY.get(0).get(0);
```

And my list is populated like this...

```
mListSelectedsSDAY = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < mListTimeBand.size(); i++) { 
    List<List<String>> tmp2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); 
    for (int j = 0; j < mListTimeBand.get(i).getTimeBandDefList().getTimeBandDefini().size(); j++) { 
        List<String> tmp1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        if (mListTimeBand.get(i).getTimeBandDefList().getTimeBandDefini().get(j).isAllSpeci‌​alDays()) { 
            for (int t = 0; t < mListSDayType.size(); t++) { 
                tmp1.add(mListSDayType.get(t).getSpecialDayName()); 
            } 
        }
        tmp2.add(tmp1); 
    }

    mListSelectedsSDAY.add(tmp2); 
}
```

However my code it always giving the following error...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Could someone please help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: Doesn't give me any error on my box. Please make sure you're declaring `private List<List<List<String>>> mListSelectedsWeekDAY;` the correct way. Can you please show more of your code, specially on how you populate `mListSelectedsWeekDAY`? Also as Thilo says, compiler should shout at you.

Comment: You got a `String[]` in there. Against the type annotation. How did you put that in the list? There should be a compiler warning somewhere.

Comment: Add more code to question. I believe the error is raised on some other line and not what you think.

Answer (score -1):

One possible situation may be is that, in your series of Get methods(), you are moving ahead to get Strings and assigning it to List variables.

Comment: i declare:
mListSelectedsSDAY = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>();        
for (int i = 0; i < mListTimeBand.size(); i++) {
 List<List<String>> tmp2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
 for (int j = 0; j < mListTimeBand.get(i).getTimeBandDefList().getTimeBandDefini().size(); j++) {
  List<String> tmp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  if (mListTimeBand.get(i).getTimeBandDefList().getTimeBandDefini().get(j).isAllSpecialDays()) {
   for (int t = 0; t < mListSDayType.size(); t++) {
    tmp1.add(mListSDayType.get(t).getSpecialDayName());
   }
  }
  tmp2.add(tmp1);
 }
 mListSelectedsSDAY.add(tmp2);
}

Answer (score -1):

You actually have a `List<List<String>>`, not a `List<List<List<String>>>`.

You must be using a raw `List` type somewhere for this to happen

Comment: as you recommended:
List mListSelectedsSDAY = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>();
???
:)